# spsolve overloading and rowvec type conversion consistency

Tags: type-conversion, armadillo, submatrix

With the following declarations:

`uvec basis;
rowvec c;
sp_mat B;`

The expression c(basis) seems to return an
`arma::subview_elem1<double, arma::Mat<unsigned int> >` and the following call appears to work:

```
vec pi_B = spsolve(trans(B), c(basis), "superlu");
```

How does `spsolve` resolve this input?

Also `vec pi_B = spsolve(trans(B), trans(c(basis)), "superlu");` throws a dimensional mismatch error but the following runs:

```
rowvec d;
vec pi_B2 = spsolve(trans(B), trans(d), "superlu");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat), `c(basis)` is a non-contiguous submatrix, where `basis` specifies which elements in `c` to use.

In this case `c` is "... interpreted as one long vector, with column-by-column ordering of the elements" and that "... the aggregate set of the specified elements is treated as a column vector", which means that `c(basis)` produces a column vector.